# Should I still use joist hangers when building a deck with all joists on blocks?

Tags: deck

I changed the layout of the decking on a free-standing front porch I am building.

**Original design:** Deck blocks with 4x4 posts under double 2x8 beams. joists to the beams using hangers.

**New (lower) design:** joists set directly in castle-type deck blocks: no beams, no posts. 18" off the ground.

I could return the hangers and toenail the rim joists directly to the ends of the span joists and cover with skirting.

But I am left wondering if there is ***still some benefit to using the joist hangers*** even if the joists aren't actually "hanging" at all but are supported by the blocks. Such as keeping the joists completely vertical, etc...

Some questioned why set joists on castles - deck is replacing a large cement step set on an even larger cement pad. I demolished the step but cannot demo the pad. Then I realized it is level and sloped already so I can use it as the base. Doing so means I only have 17" total height to work with to keep under the door sill, which meant no room for conventional beam.

Also, this is floating, free-standing construction that is exempt from all permitting where I live - I already checked into that with my zb.

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. A couple of pictures of your current setup would certainly help ensure others are accurately seeing what you're describing. [Edit] your post, then click the "sun & mountain" icon above the text entry box to upload the pics for hosting.

Comment: All that said, joist hangers will help ensure that your joists are firmly held in place, even if they're not hanging. Depending on your location, they may be required even if the whole thing is sitting on the ground. If this is permitted work, a call to _your_ inspector (department) may be in order.

Comment: What's the point of setting _every_ joist on a block? The challenge I predict is getting them all perfectly level. That's the main benefit (aside from cost) of using a conventional flush beam on just a few blocks.

Comment: there is some benefit to the hangers, (they are stronger than toe nailing) but I can't say this this is a significant benefit.

Comment: @isherwood because there is a cement pad properly level and sloped under 2/3 the area the deck will cover.

Comment: So you have to accommodate the slope (decks aren't usually sloped), which reinforces the benefit of a flush beam.

Comment: @isherwood I have only 17" height to work with and I want the slope since it the decking will be perpendicular to entrance and will have snow on it much of the year. I updated my question with more background on it.... thanks!

Comment: You misunderstand. A flush beam is on the same plane as the joists. Also, a thing can't be level and sloped at the same time. :) You definitely don't want a wooden deck sloped in a snowy climate. It'll be slippery enough as it is without bringing gravity into the equation. It wouldn't do you any real good anyway. Trust me--no one slopes wooden decks in the northland.

Comment: @isherwood you are correct- I see what you mean by a flush beam - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Coming back much later to say "yes" and "I did" and here's why:

Just because they are called "hangers" doesn't mean that's their sole purpose. They tie the verticals in such a way that they stay vertical and resist tipping. They also are connected firmly to the ends.

As some commented, putting every joist in a castle block leads to problems with keeping the deck flat across the surface since now you have to ensure all the blocks are level- much harder to do and no guarantee they don't heave anyway. Plus they are too close together, etc.

So I used 6 castle blocks to support the deck and it worked fine.

Comment: Guess I should have made an answer out of my comment 2 years ago... :)